# SQL Query to JOIN tables having different values

Tags: sql

I have come across a situation where i need to join two table based on columns have different values.

E.g.

- `Table1` has column `T1`
- `Table2` has column `T2`
- `T1` has 100 rows with value `P`

and

- `T2` has 50 rows with value `N` and 50 rows with value `P`

I want to join table `Table1` with value `P` with `Table2` that has values `N` as well as `P`

It should give me total 100 records.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? This is basic SQL, so please post your current query and explain what is not working.

Comment: i was not able to find syntax. Hence havent build any stuff to post here. If you know, please help out.

Comment: Both the fields t1 and t2 are having same datatype char. But here i want to join records having t1 value as 'P' with data from another table column t2 having values as 'P' and 'N' both.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Are you want to see this tables side by side?

Comment: no i want to see it as a single table. Columns should be side by side.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.t1, 
  t2.t2
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.t2 IN('N', 'P')
WHERE T1.t1 = 'p';
```

- The predicate `IN ('N', 'P')` will get the values of t2 from the table2 that have the values `N` and `P`.
- The `WHERE` clause will get the values of t1 form the tabale1 where the the value is `P`, you  can move this predicate to the `JOIN` condition.

Answer (score 1):

A `cross join` repeats every row in the right table for every row in the left table.  You can then specify any "unrelated" conditions in the `where` clause:

```
select  *
from    Table1 t1
cross join
        Table2 t2
where   t1.col1 = 'N'
        and t2.col1 in ('N', 'P')
```

Answer (score 0):

**In your scenario any join will act as a cross join** since you have many duplicates in both 
tables (Table1 with 100 rows of 'P' and Table2 with 50 rows of 'P'),

```
select  t1.*,t2.*
from    Table1 t1
join    Table2 t2
where   t1.field1 = 'N'
        and t2.field1 IN ('N', 'P')
```

And your requirement to get only 100 rows is not possible. Because, first row of 'P' in table1 will get be joined with 50 rows of table2 with 'P' and so **you will get 50 rows in output for each row of table1.** 
And if you really want 100 rows then put a `LIMIT` OR `TOP` as a filter condition.

Hope this helps you!!!

Comment: The default `join` is `inner join`.  A `cross join` has to be written out :)

Comment: yeah @Andomar edited. But anyways in this case, inner and cross join will give the same result right?? Things I have written out are correct rigth. Pls give feedback incase anything is wrong..

Comment: default is inner join but writing as 'join' also will do the job right?? @Andomar

Comment: `t1 join t2` will give a syntax error for a missing `on` clause.  You're right that `t1 join t2 on 1=1` and `t1 cross join t2` will give the same result.